# What is the Meaning of Return False in a Php Function

Tags: php, mysql

i wanted to know what is the meaning of return False in an function.

go Through this function:

```
function reset_password($password,$user_id)
{
    $sql="UPDATE user SET password='$password' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";

    if(!mysql_query($sql,$this->mycon))
    {
        array_push($this->err_msg,"Error in Inserting - ".mysql_error($this->mycon));
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Reset Password code.
    }   
}
```

in this function i wanted to know what is the meaning of return false.

Comment: That totally depends on how the *caller* reacts to the return value of the function...

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm gonna set my password to "*blahblah'; update user set password = 'w00t';*".

Comment: @GrandmasterB `mysql_query` only supports one SQL statement at a time. My password would be "w00t' -- "

Answer (score 1):

The return value of a function, in general, is a part of the convention between the caller and the callee. It is a way for the caller to determine what was the outcome of the function execution.

Specifically conceerning your example, this function returns `false` in the case of failure to reset the password. The caller can take advantage of this information and act accordingly. For example:

```
$outcome=$anObj->reset_password('opensessame','some_user');
if($outcome)
  echo "Password was successfully reset.";
else
  {
  $err=$anObj->err_msg[count($anObj->err_msg)-1]; // last element
  echo "Password Reset Failure because: $err";
  }
```

But this is not to be interpreted as "*a `false` return value means something went wrong*". Many functions return `false` because that's the real outcome of the execution upon success. Consider for example `in_array()`. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

> ### Description
>
> `bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict =
>   FALSE ] )`
>
> Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is
>   set.
>
> ### Return Values
>
> Returns TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.